# How can I set a controller for a particular url in magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, url-routing

The reason I want to do this is because I want two different urls to make use of the same controller. I.e. `/mymodule/mycontroller` and `/mymodule/mycontroller2` should use the same controller `Mypackage_Mymodule_Mycontroller`

Is it possible to do this in the config.xml? Or do I have to manipulate the router?

I prefer to set config files instead of manipulating the router. In a ZendFramework app this could be done in routes.ini as follow

```
routes.myroute.route = "/mymodule/mycontroller2"
routes.myroute.defaults.module = "mymodule"
routes.myroute.defaults.controller = "mycontroller"
```

Is there a similar way in Magento?

For SEO reasons I don't want to use rewrite.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this (edit) *THREE* ways:

1. Have `mycontroller2` extend `mycontroller` and override/extend action methods as appropriate - but this does not seem to be what you want.
2. Use the somewhat-deprecated config-based URL rewrites, which allow you to point one controller to another (ref [`Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_rewrite()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L839):

   ```
   <global>
       <routers>
           <mymodule><!-- match your routers config node -->
               <rewrite>
                   <mycontroller2><!-- match your controller name -->
                       <override_actions>true</override_actions>
                       <to>mymodule/mycontroller</to>
                   </mycontroller2>
               </rewrite>
           </mymodule>
       </routers> 
   </global>
   ```

   Also, you will need to create a dummy controller action to handle all rewrites (this is the big problem with this deprecated rewrite style). Given your requirement, the following should work:

   ```
   <?php

   class My_Module_MyController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
   {
       public function __call($doesnt,$matter)
       {
           //empty...
       }
   }
   ```
3. And I've just determined that you can skip the configuration altogether:

   ```
   class My_Module_Mycontroller2Controller extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
   {
       public function __call($action,$matter)
       {
           $method = preg_split('/Action/',$action);
           $this->_forward(
               $method[0],
               'mycontroller',
               'mymodule'
           );
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Yeah the 3rd option is clean and consistent. It's a pity Magento does not support a "controllerName" tag under `<routers>`. Many thanks for the answer. Just a little hint; I prefer to use `substr` or `str_replace` to extract fix-length strings.

Comment: Ah, but consider a method named `someActionAction`!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you dont want to use htaccess rewrites. So just to make sure in case you dont know it: Magento has a nice rewrite system built in. Sorry for posting just a supid link, but by having a look at it you can easily solve this task...

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/seo/how_to_work_with_magento_url_rewrite_rules

Comment: I know I can get this approach with a rewrite. Nevertheless I prefer a solution defining a route either extending `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard` or defining the controller in the config file within <routers>. The later option doesn't seem to be possible.